# Looking for a better way to dynamically pick a column source in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

To start with an example, lets say I need an SQL view with a structure like:

```
ID | Text01 | Text02 | Text03 | Text04 | Text05
```

Depending on the type of item, what is stored in each column could change, for example item with ID 1 may use 'Length' in Text01 while ID 2 may use Text02 to store length.

Now assume there is another table that explains the mapping:

```
ID | Text01 | Text02
--------------------
1  | Length | 
2  |        | Length
```

I want a way to directly populate the query based on the mapping.

I know I could use a case statement, eg.

```
case when mapping.text01 = 'length' then sourcetable.length ...
```

However my actual scenario consists of 40 dynamic columns and up to 150 fields which could be mapped to a column, which makes this option less viable.

Is there any way to convert the text of "sourcetable.length" to a column source or any other ideas you can recommend to potentially simplify this process?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lousy data structure because you are storing data across the tables in columns rather than in rows.

You can do what you want, basically by unpivoting the data and then joining:

```
with t1 as (
      select t1.id, v.colname, v.colvalue
      from table1 t1 cross apply
           (values ('Text01', t1.Text01),
                   ('Text02', t1.Text02),
                   ('Text03', t1.Text03),
                   . . .
           ) v(colname, colvalue)
     ),
     t2 as (
      select m.id, v.colname, v.colfield
      from mapping m cross apply
           (values ('Text01', m.Text01),
                   ('Text02', m.Text02),
                   ('Text03', m.Text03),
                   . . .
           ) v(colname, colfield)
     )
select t1.id, t2.colfield, t1.colvalue
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.colname = t2.colname;
```

If you want the data in a single row, then you would have to re-pivot the results.